# Django sql statements with non english symbols

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django

I have sql statement, with non english symbols in `where`

(`sap_code` variable contains russian text)

```
sap_code = 'ОВОЩИ – ФРУКТЫ'
sql_string = 'SELECT ' \
            'SAP_CODE, ' \
            'SKU, ' \
        'FROM INFO ' \
        f'WHERE ROWNUM < {settings.NQ_SQL_LIMIT}'
if sap_code:
    sql_string += f' AND SAP_CODE = {sap_code}'
with connections[db].cursor() as cursor:
    exec_result = cursor.execute(
        sql_string
    )
```

And I get such error `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character` (oracle database)

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Try national character literals, `N'ОВОЩИ'`, and nchar data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Oracle limitation. You will need to quote your non-ASCII characters. I've changed your final fragment to double quotes and then quoted the internal string. That should resolve this issue if you're dead-set on using raw SQL here.

```py
sap_code = 'ОВОЩИ – ФРУКТЫ'
sql_string = 'SELECT ' \
             'SAP_CODE, ' \
             'SKU, ' \
             'FROM INFO ' \
             f'WHERE ROWNUM < {settings.NQ_SQL_LIMIT}'
if sap_code:
    sql_string += f" AND SAP_CODE = '{sap_code}'"
with connections[db].cursor() as cursor:
    exec_result = cursor.execute(
        sql_string
    )
```